# Smallest $n$ that is divisible by all numbers smaller than n

Tags: number-theory

So after reading a lot of questions like "what's the smallest number divisible by $1..10$, I thought about another question. Find the smallest number $n\in \mathbb{N}, n>2$ s.t. $n$ is divisible by all numbers below $n$, so $1..n$.

I tried finding this number, but I think such an $n$ does not exist. As e.g. the smallest number being divisible by $1..10$ is 2520, I think that there always is a prime number $p$ between $\sqrt{n}$ ($n$'s largest prime factor) and $n$ s.t.  $p$ is not divisible by $n$. But I don't know if this always holds.

However, I don't really know if there is some statement that could help me to show that such an $n$ does not exist or if there even exists this $n$.

Comment: Such a number does not exist. If $n>2$ then $n$ can't be divisible by $n-1$.

Comment: @Mark Ah, I didn't see $n>2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there is some $n$ such that it is divisible by all the numbers smaller than itself. In particular, $n - 1 | n$. Therefore, there is an integer $k$ such that

$$n = k \left( n - 1 \right)$$

On simplifying,

$$\left( k - 1 \right)n = k$$

Also, since $k | n$, $\dfrac{n}{k}$ is an integer and the multiplicative inverse of $k - 1$. This is possible only when $k - 1 = \dfrac{n}{k} = \pm 1$

Both the possibilities reduce to $n = 2$. Therefore, such an $n > 2$ is not possible.

Comment: Perhaps more simply, if $n>2$ and $n=k(n-1)$ then $1<k=1+\frac {1}{n-1}<2$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $n = 3$ is not a solution. For $n > 3$ If $n = 2k+1$ is odd, it is not divisible by $k$ and if $n = 2k$ is even, it is not divisible by $k+1$. Hence such a $n$ does not exist.